# Uncaught TypeError in React Client

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, anchor-client

I want to create an account that will hold data for my program on the client side. I've imported the dependencies I need for that:

```
import web3 from '@project-serum/anchor';
```

and I go ahead to create the account:

```
let baseAccount = web3.Keypair.generate();
```

However, when I run the code using `npm run start`, I get the following error in my console:

```
react-dom.development.js:23275 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generate')
```

The error seems to come from the `generate` function I call above. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you supplied to me privately it turns out that the version of `@solana/web3.js` you have is 0.90.5, much before `Keypair` was introduced to the code.

You can either upgrade `@project-serum/anchor` to the latest version, or you can force a newer version of `@solana/web3.js` to be used through [Yarn resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/).